# Flex and AIR passing data between each other

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air

I’m looking for some samples/tutorials/general pointers in doing either of the following.

1)    Create an AIR app that can load a live flex app and use that for testing.  So we have a app which is live and if I could load that into a AIR app which can edit a config file and then test that config file  using the live swf but inside the AIR app to make sure that if doesn’t break the flex app before uploading new config for the live app.

2)    Or I’ve heard of being able to drag data from an AIR app into a flex app.  If so then the AIR app could pass the test data across to the flex app and it would refresh and we could see whether it works or not.

I've looked into this a bit now and it looks like using the clipboard and some javascript seems like the way forward.  Save data in clipboard from AIR app then read clipboard using javascript and send to flex app.  Has anyone any other ways of transferring data between AIR & flex.

Also 'You cannot access shared objects across sandbox boundaries.' is from Adobe docs which I'm presumming means that an AIR app can't share the same 'flash cookie' as a flex app. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Has anyone any other ways of
>   transferring data between AIR & flex.*

[`flash.net.LocalConnection`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) is the standard method of doing this, and although it has its quirks, it works quite well. This is what I use to transfer data from a Flex app (that's running in a browser, although it shouldn't matter whether it's running in the browser plugin or the stand-alone Flash Player) to an AIR app.

Comment: this looks to be the thing. the docs on this say 'Between content (SWF-based or HTML-based) in an AIR application and SWF content running in a browser', cheers.